# Swift: (Countdown app) How to make date picker choose the due date?

Tags: xcode, swift

Making a countdown app and instead of manually adding the due date i want to be able to do it with a date picker.

Here is the code i am using now. What i need help with is implementing code that let's me do this by using the date picker (The competitionDate).

```
 // Here we set the current date

let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second, .Nanosecond], fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
let month = components.month
let year = components.year
let day = components.day


let currentDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)



// here we set the due date. When the timer is supposed to finish
// final Calendar value

let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


let competitionDate = NSDateComponents()
competitionDate.year = 2015
competitionDate.month = 6
competitionDate.day = 21
competitionDate.hour = 08
competitionDate.minute = 00
let competitionDay = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(competitionDate)!


// Here we compare the two dates
competitionDay.timeIntervalSinceDate(currentDate!)


let dayCalendarUnit = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: date)
```

Comment: let currentDate = NSDate()

Comment: BTW competitionDate.timeIntervalSinceNow or datePicker.date.timeIntervalSinceNow

Answer (score 0):

you mean to get the date of the date picker?
you can do it like so:

```
let date:NSDate = datePicker.date
```